# Delete folders which are exactly x days older not more than or less than

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7

I want to delete folders which are exactly x days old. Not more than Or less than. Could anyone please help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what have you tried? How do you assume that you should approach such a problem?

Comment: Have tried find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \; but which will delete all files older than 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a regular find:

```
find /path/to/directory/  -mtime <x days> -delete
```

and from the manual entry of `find` you will see:

```
   -mtime n
        The value of n can be one of the following values:
          n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 seconds (with any remainder discarded), is n. 86400 seconds is 24 hours.
          -n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 seconds (with any remainder discarded), is less than n.
          +n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 seconds (with any remainder discarded), is greater than n (in case of UNIX03, greater than n+1).
        Note: The definition of -mtime is changed to comply with the Single UNIX Specification, Version 3. The previous behavior of -mtime evaluated as True if the file is modified in n-1 to n multiples of 24 hours. By default, find -mtime works like
        it did before UNIX03. The UNIX03 behavior can be obtained by setting the environment variables XPG_SUS_ENV to ON and XPG_UNIX98 to OFF.
```

so without signs you will get exact period.